# error C2228: left of '.draw' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

ok, I think that the problem is that I haven't initialized the vector
but I dont know... anyway, I am getting an error saying that this is wrong:

```
drawable.at(i).draw();
```

with the vector being declared in the header file as:

```
vector<render*> drawable;
```

its a vector of render pointers as I have a whole bunch of classes that need to be drawn and they are all children of a parent with pure virtual functions in it, is this the wrong way?

btw, to put a child in I used this:
header:

```
ShaysWorld * sw;
```

cpp:

```
sw = new ShaysWorld;
drawable.push_back(sw);
```

What can I do to fix the left of '.draw' problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`drawable.at(i)->draw();` because drawable.at(i) is a render **pointer**

Answer (score 1):

[Try Out LLVM](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi):

```
_484_0.cc:8:20: error: member reference type 'Renderer *' is a pointer;
                       maybe you meant to use '->'?
    renderers.at(i).draw();
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
                   ->
1 error generated.
```

Or how using a great compiler improves the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that the problem is that I haven't initialized the vector

No. You should be able to figure out immediately that this isn't the problem, because you're getting the error from the compiler. Failing to initialize things causes problems when the program runs. You haven't run it yet, because it hasn't compiled, because you're getting a compiler error message.

> its a vector of render pointers

Yes, it is. So when you get an element from that vector, you have a pointer. You can't call a member function on a pointer, because a pointer isn't an object - it points to the object.

That's what the error message is saying: "left of '.draw' must have class/struct/union". That means exactly what it says: the thing that's on the left of `.draw` is `drawable.at(i)`, and the type of that expression isn't a class, struct, or union - it's a pointer-to-class.

Comment: Nitpicking, but technically a pointer can be an object and in this case it is. It would be more accurate to say that you can't call a member function on a pointer because pointer types don't have members.